# Liferay 6.1 get themeDisplay in velocity (vm) file

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I'm trying to get the profile picture of my users and display it in my liferay theme. So far I've been able to access the `User` object trough the velocity `$user` variable. The user model has a method called `getPortraitUrl()` which takes `ThemeDisplay` as a parameter. I've read in the liferay documentation that the `themeDisplay` object is available at runtime when working with themes, but I can't seem to make this work.

I've tried several different ways to get the `themeDisplay` object and none of them seem to work:

- `$theme`
- `$themeDisplay`
- `$request.get("theme-display")`
- `$theme_display`

... and several other methods that return nothing.

**`$user.getPortraitUrl($themeDisplay)`** is what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful that the correct method is `getPortraitURL(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay)`, **URL** is in uppercase.

Try this:

```
$user.getPortraitURL($themeDisplay)
```

You should also be able to use `$themeDisplay`. 

[Access Objects from Velocity](http://www.liferay.com/it/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity) is useful link for all liferay velocity variables.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you need to use for ThemeDisplay is

**$theme_display**

Comment: Yeah, I tried that one too and didn't work. Could it be that the use of this variable is disabled somewhere in liferay's properties files? I'm totally lost on this one.

Comment: I assume you are logged in try adding below in your vm 
  $theme_display
  $user
  $user.getPortraitURL($theme_display)
It should display $theme_display as a object and entire user details for logged in user and Portrait URL like /image/user_male_portrait?img_id=0&t=1380865596111. It worked for me. Which version of Liferay you are using ?